# Route for one resource returns two records insted of one

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

In my application I want route to resource "day" to looke like this "sampledomain.com/day/1-3-2014".

I defined it like this:

```
this.resource('day', { path: '/day/:day_date' });
```

My model hook for that route looks like this:

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('day', params.day_date);
},
```

And my API response looks like this:

```
{"day":{"id":"3","dayDate":"2014-03-01","openTime":null,"closeTime":null}}
```

For some reason I'm getting two records into the store. One is correct and one with id set like the dynamic part from URL (1-3-2014) and the rest of this model data as empty.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretending the date is the id, so Ember Data is building up a record based on the id `1-3-2014` then your server is returning a record with an id of `3`.  So that begs the question, which is the id?

If dayDate can be the id, the primaryKey for the record should change, if it can't, then really you should be using `findQuery` (or find with an object).

```
return this.store.find('day', {dayDate: params.day_date});
```

This will change your result set to a collection, since you aren't going by id, it's no longer guaranteed to be a single instance.

Additionally the get request will be different

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `findQuery` and return the first record inside the promise resolve handler:

```
App.DayRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('day', { date: params.day_date }).then(function(days) {
      return days.toArray()[0];
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: days will actually always exist, and to get an object from an Ember Data collection you will want to use `objectAt` instead of the indexer